# What should printf("%.15e", 1e23); print?

Tags: c, floating-point, printf, double, libgcc

I am experimenting with optimizing double->text conversion (trying to beat grissu, ryu etc...).

While doing so, I am comparing my results with `sprintf` outputs. Now I have encountered the above interesting case.

```
printf("%.15e", 1e23);
```

(e.g. glibc) prints

**9.999999999999999e+22**

while my routine prints

**1.000000000000000e+23**

Now both numbers are the same distance from the "true value" and converting both these values back (e.g. with `atof`) yields the same double.

However, I believe my result satisfies "round to even" rule (which is the reason it went this way).

Which result is more correct?

Comment: It's refreshing to see a floating-point question that's not just a variation of "is floating point math broken?" ;-) Sorry, I don't know the answer though.

Comment: Just a question: what do you mean with _glibc prints_? I mean, how do you get the result from glibc?

Comment: @DavidRanieri from `printf`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *same distance from the "true value"*. The second case is *exactly* the true value, isn't it?

Comment: @AdrianMole it isn't. The exact value is 0x1.52d02c7e14af6p+76

Comment: @AdrianMole not necessarily, the number may not have an exact binary representation

Comment: @AnttiHaapala ahhh ok, I was assuming something like `gdb > print 1e23 with some precision`, thanks :)

Comment: the exact value from my Python 3 interpreter using arbitrary integer math is 99999999999999991611392

Comment: @AnttiHaapala OK. I see. Printing with `.30e` precision shows `9.999999999999999161139200000000e+22`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`1e23` is [typically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) not exactly represented as a `double`.

The  2 closest choices are:

```
// %a           v     %f 
0x1.52d02c7e14af6p+76  99999999999999991611392.000000
0x1.52d02c7e14af7p+76 100000000000000008388608.000000
```

There are both 8388608.0 from  100000000000000000000000.0, one above, one below.

Typically the selected one in tie cases is the *even* one.  (See last bit in hex format.)

99999999999999991611392.000000 is the winner and so an output of `"9.999999999999999e+22"` is expected.

When printing with more the `DBL_DIG` (15) significant digits, (`"%.15e"` prints 16 significant digits) this *problem* is possible as code is effectively doing a text-`double`-text round-trip and exceeding what `double` can round-trip.

---

> I am experimenting with optimizing double->text conversion

I recommend to also use `"%a"` to gain deeper understanding.

Comment: Thank you for the analysis. I turned out that choosing that other value is an artifact of my algorithm - it is (was) based on converting the value to integer (with corresponding number of digits) which is rounded with "binary" rules - thus that ...1611.. part rounds it up. Back to the drawing board :)

Comment: @MirekFidler Once working, consider https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: 1e22 is often the higher power-of-2 encode-able in a `double`.